# Is it common for universities to have scientific development plans?

Tags: research-process, science, research-group, politics

Many times, research teams and departments just perform research on topics that the Department Chair or Research Head initiate -- but do some universities structure their research, postdocs, and departments according to an encompassing plan or agenda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Universities love to add bureaucratic layers and it is quite common for a university (or schools within universities) to carry out strategic planning to identify research priorities. A quick search reveals

[Harvard Medical School's strategic plan](http://hms.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/assets/About_Us/Off_Dean/files/P1_p.pdf) is to "Seize rapidly expanding opportunities in biomedical research to increase human well-being" and identifies human genetics, therapeutic discovery, neuroscience, bioengineering, immunology and microbial sciences, stem cell and regenerative biology, and systems biology as key areas that have the potential to connect fundamental science with clinical applications.

[Boston University's strategic plan](http://www.bu.edu/president/strategic-plan/plan.shtml) includes a an "emphasis on interdisciplinary research and graduate education in order to expand our leadership in important fields and the collaborative atmosphere across our campuses." They are ["especially targeting"](http://www.bu.edu/research/our-research/research-areas/) Data Science, Engineering Biology, Global Health, Infectious Diseases, Neuroscience, Photonics, and Urban Health.

[University of Nottingham's research priority areas](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/research/global-research-themes/index.aspx) of Cultures and Communication, Digital Futures, Health and Wellbeing, Sustainable Societies, and Transformative Technologies

Comment: Documents that look impressive to outsiders based on their mere volume are created, yes. But are they in any way linked to what is actually happening with the research at the institution? My impression is that frequently, so-called "mission statements" are more like empty marketing phrases by the PR department (or, granted, PR-conscious professors) than anything that has a real bearing on the scientific workings of the university; possibly with the "mission statement" being written after the fact, describing the current competences and some likely extrapolation into the future.

Answer (score 5):

In the United States, at least, this does not generally happen except at a very coarse level.  Thus, for example, many universities engage in ["cluster hiring"](https://www.insidehighered.com/advice/2013/09/30/essay-how-colleges-can-engage-cluster-hiring) in which a number of positions are hired together as a strategic investment in making something interesting happen in a particular area, often coupled with some internal monies being set aside to support collaboration between those hires.  Likewise, a department may often decide to hire in a particular area where they wish to grow or to shore up weakness, or a university may set up an internal funding program for something that it is interested in.

Once faculty have been hired, however, the traditions of scientific freedom of inquiry mean that it would be looked on very askance for any person or group to try to assign faculty to work on specific research projects as part of their job.

Comment: Isn't cluster hiring and targeted internal funding a scientific plan?

Comment: @StrongBad Absolutely, on a very coarse level, as noted in my answer.  It's nothing like the much more precise and structured targets that you will often see in other parts of the scientific community, such as the organizations that directly construct and operate large shared resources like telescopes, particle colliders, or gene banks.

Answer (score 4):

Typically not in academic departments, but many universities have organized research units that are not academic departments, don't offer degrees, and don't teach courses (to first order) but they do compete for research grants, hire research professionals, and do conduct research. There can be some centralized strategizing about what such units should pursue, though they are probably more often allowed to run quite independently. I work for such a center which also provides supercomputing resources to the university, state, and country as well as doing stuff that looks like academic research.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How are these organized, strategic research units called? I wonder what positions exist in them? Obviously not professorships, so ate employees position titles like Scientist, Advisor, or....??

Comment: My university calls them Organized Research Units, but I don't think this category is all that common. They might be known elsewhere as centers, or institutes, or other synonyms. We hire Research Associates, Research Scientists, Postdocs and other categories of folks.

Answer (score 0):

> research teams and departments just perform research on topics that the Department Chair or Research Head initiate

Other than in very broad terms (barely beyond the decision which institutes are set up and financed), things are even much less directed: Especially in universities, research teams and departments in many cases perform research whose direction is very much determined by the personal interests of the researchers in those teams, and also vaguely influenced by whatever grants happened to have lately been acquired.

> do some universities structure their research, postdocs, and departments according to an encompassing plan or agenda?

It happens on various levels, but usually not in the form of a big masterplan that encompasses all research, but rather as single strategic moves:

- A university may choose to support a specific area that the university wants to strengthen in its profile.
- Likewise, an institute may choose to intentionally find a researcher who works on a particular area to widen the institute's portfolio in that area and thereby increase chances to get related grants in the future.

So, these structured efforts run in parallel with a large amount of less structured (or rather, "self-directing") research going on.

Comment: What's the downvote for?